# If I have the cell #. switch ID and name, can I locate an physical address?

Tags: authentication

Only a PRO can help me!  My husband had an affair, said it was over five years ago and I should not be concerned, ever again.  Yet, the result was devastating, medically with cancer. I believe people rarely change, only opportunities and circumstances therefore, I need to know if I should move on. It's important because my only son deserves more and me as well.

Initially, there was much transparency, allowing me to see call logs and more.  Then, he insisted that cell phone calls be made via Wifi to eliminate data usage. But, he tripped.  One call log showed "an incoming call to himself from his own cell number."  Well, this is impossible therefore I asked him to call Sprint in front of me.  The result, someone in New York called him via his Wifi but when he asks Sprint to disclose the number, they said they could not for security reasons.  He knew this, that they would not disclose.  He is a tech (but not with years of experience).

If I have my husbands cell number, MEID, and IP address does this help?

Now the worst.  She (I have her name) and her cell phone (I have this too), was purchased by him five years ago. He says the account is in her name, that he simply purchased the cell phone but I believe this can't be true because she had no social security number and is an illegally here in the U.S.A. When I made him call the carrier T-Mobile, they said no change could be made.  Now that the above occurred recently in 2015, I researched on the internet to see if the carrier is still the same.  The internet tells me that it is now serviced by Nextel and I know Sprint owns them.  And, additional information was found, a "Switch ID".

If I'm wrong, I apologize profusely for being a spy but I do need help and thank you in advance for any consideration. Or, teach me and direct me regarding steps that I can take to see and protect myself.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not actually an Infosec question as per our scope. It is actually a question about what telecoms providers will give you. Simply put - they will not give a private individual this information, so no, you can't locate it.